# When does strong convergence imply convergence in operator norm?

Tags: reference-request, semigroup-of-operators, strong-convergence

I have a $C_0$-semigroup $(T_t)_{t\ge0}$ and I want **to show**

> $\lim_{t \to \infty} T_t =0 $ with respect to the operator norm.

After some effort, **I was able to prove**

> $\lim_{t \to \infty} T_t =0 $ with respect to the strong operator topology.

Now I know that in general strong convergence doesn't imply convergence in operator norm. Therefore my question is the following:

> What additional conditions on $(T_t)_{t\geq 0}$ or its generator $A$ are sufficient for strong convergence to imply convergence in operator norm?

I would be happy to be provided with some references too.

Comment: In addition to Pedro's answer, a sufficient condition to get uniform convergence to $0$ from strong convergence to $0$ is *quasi-compactness* of the semigroup - see for instance Theorem V.3.1 in the semigroup book by Engel and Nagel (2000).

Answer (score 4):

Since your semigroup is $C_0$, if it satisfies some condition according to which "strong convergence implies convergence in operator norm", then it is uniformly continuous (which I suspect is not the case). Therefore, you probably should try another strategy. For this, the following result can be useful.

> For a $C_0$-semigroup $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ on a Banach space $X$ with generator $A$, the following assertions are equivalent.
>
> 1. $\|T(t)\|\overset{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ (uniform stability).
> 2. $e^{\varepsilon t}\|T(t)\|\overset{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ (uniform exponential stability).
> 3. $e^{\varepsilon t}\|T(t)x\|\overset{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ for all $x\in X$ and some $\varepsilon>0$.
> 4. $\|T(t_0)\|< 1$ for some $t_0>0$.
> 5. $r(T(t_0))<1$ for some $t_0>0$, where $r$ is the spectral radius.
> 6. $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty\|T(t)x\|^p\, dt<\infty$ for some/all $p\in[1,\infty)$ and all $x\in X$ (Datko-Pazy Theorem).
> 7. If $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ is eventually norm continuous:
>    $s(A)<0$, where $s$ is the spectral bound.
> 8. If $X$ is Hilbert:
>    $\{\lambda\mid \operatorname{Re}\lambda>0\}\subset\rho(A)$ and $\displaystyle \sup_{\operatorname{Re}\lambda>0}\|(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\|<\infty$ (Gearhart-Prüss Theorem).
> 9. If $X$ is Hilbert and $(T(t)_{t\geq 0}$ is of contractions:
>    $\mathbf{i}\mathbb{R}\subset\rho(A)$ and $\displaystyle \limsup_{|\lambda|\to\infty}\|(\mathbf{i}\lambda I-A)^{-1}\|<\infty$ (Gearhart-Prüss Theorem).

*Source:* [Engel & Nagel](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA296&lpg=PA296&dq=A+first+stability+concept,+called+uniform+exponential+stability,+has+already+been+introduced+in+Definition+I.3.11.&source=bl&ots=2RWc1D9N3F&sig=ACfU3U0a66voV0zR39yYQAQZs-Kd3Vj5HQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXosuv5PPoAhUNK7kGHSxeBS4Q6AEwAHoECAsQLA#v=onepage&q=A%20first%20stability%20concept%2C%20called%20uniform%20exponential%20stability%2C%20has%20already%20been%20introduced%20in%20Definition%20I.3.11.&f=false) and [Liu & Zheng](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ReG5eHHshpoC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=In+the+following+we+give+the+proof+of+equivalence+of+these+two+results+under+the+condition+that&source=bl&ots=XQWZgKtgwQ&sig=ACfU3U0KNKLdpTAUedzEKcgRxMtv8QKsVA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYo97W5PPoAhXqH7kGHaFFCN8Q6AEwAHoECAgQLA#v=onepage&q=In%20the%20following%20we%20give%20the%20proof%20of%20equivalence%20of%20these%20two%20results%20under%20the%20condition%20that&f=false). Other equivalences can be found in [Neerven](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=jl32BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&dq=Our+main+concern+is+finding+necessary+and+sufficient+conditions+for+uniform+exponential+stability.&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpn--A5vPoAhUNJ7kGHQtVCoIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Our%20main%20concern%20is%20finding%20necessary%20and%20sufficient%20conditions%20for%20uniform%20exponential%20stability.&f=false).

Comment: Could you provide a reason/reference for: if it satisfies some condition according to which "strong convergence implies convergence in operator norm", then it is uniformly continuous"?

Comment: @Mark Suppose that, for your semigroup, strong convergence implies convergence in operator norm. Since your semigroup satisfies $(T_t-I)\overset{t\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} 0$ strongly (because it is $C_0$), we conclude that $(T_t-I)\overset{t\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} 0$ with respect to the operator norm. This means that it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Ah so you meant that a condition under which strong convergence $\implies$ operator convergence always. That would, of course, be too much to ask for. I was interested more in a "local" condition due to which $T_t \to 0$ strongly would imply $\|T_t\| \to 0$ as $t\to \infty.$

Comment: @Pedro: Wonderful overview of the various conditions! May I remark that 7) is not actually equivalent to the other conditions: uniform convergence to zero does not imply eventual norm continuity (consider for instance $(e^{-t}T_t)_{t \ge 0}$, where $(T_t)_{t \ge 0}$ denotes the left shift semigroup on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thanks for the correction. I corrected the post.